# Multiple domains on 1 cloud service

Tags: dns, azure-web-roles, multiple-domains, url-masking

I have a app which is a website builder. Lets say the app is on a azure webrole and its domain is called www.myapp.com.

I want to offer a service where users can use their custom domain with my app. So User 1 has a domain called ww.user1.com, user2 has www.user2.com etc. Whenever someone types www.user1.com, I want them to be able to see come to my my app ie www.myapp.com, with the browser still showing www.user1.com. You can assume I have complete access to the DNS and nameservers of these custom domains. I just need to understand how to configure this in azure.

Comment: Is this a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487995/multiple-ssl-domains-to-one-azure-cloud-service-site?

Comment: Not really, as it was on SSL binding of multiple custom domains on a single cloud. I was trying to figure out how to hose one app on a cloud service where content changes as per custom domain end user has used to navigate to the website.

Turns out its easy, all that is required is cname config and listening to host_header on server side aspx page_init

Comment: You can put that as an answer and then self-accept, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, as it was on SSL binding of multiple custom domains on a single cloud. I was trying to figure out how to have one app on a cloud service where content changes as per custom domain end user has used to navigate to the website. Turns out its easy, all that is required is cname config and listening to host_header on server side aspx page_init –